# Return an mvc action with a viewmodel type different to the passed one

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an **ItemsController** with an Index action returning and rendering items on the client like

```
return View(itemViewModels);
```

Each itemViewModel has some bootstrap tabs. In each tab a partialView is rendered.

When the user edits a **partialView** and send the data to the **Tab1Controller** how can I return the View for the whole itemViewModel showing validation errors for the one partial view inside that tab1?

I have made the View work requesting/responsing with the sent itemViewModel but then Only the single item`s html is returned **not** the full items html.

AND when I return the Index View to the ItemsViewModels then I can NOT return my passed itemViewModels to show the validation errors.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(ItemViewModel viewModel)
    {

        return View("ItemsViewModels", viewModel);
    }
```

This code does not work because the View does not match to the viewmodel type.

But I need to show the Html of the ItemsViewModels with the invalid (data-val attributes) html of the single edited itemViewModel.

I can NOT post and return the ItemsViewModels  because it has many other properties which would make the modelstate invalid...

Do you have any idea?

**UPDATE**

I am NOT allowed to use ajax else the problem would be done quickly... this is for a common website and the customer wants a postback no ajax/SPA behavior.

At the moment I get the whole items from the service again and render it but then every ItemViewModel`s html has an invalid e.g. textbox. But I want that only a certain ItemViewModel is invalid.

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> SaveLanguage(ItemViewModel itemViewModel)
{          

     var viewModels = GetItemsViewModelsFromSErvice();

     viewModels.Items.ElementAt(0).Settings = itemViewModel;


    return View(MVC.Test.Items.Views.Index,viewModels );
}
```

Comment: Is each partial a separate form for one `ItemViewModel` (i.e is the model for the view `IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are forced to do a full postback, but each partial view contains just a form with the elements for that 1 item then you'll have to reconstruct the other items in your controller before returning.

Your controller method would be something like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var vm = GetAllItems(); //method to get all your items for first load
     return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ItemViewModel viewModel)
{
    //get the full list of items, and then replace just the altered one
    var vm = GetAllItems(); // assume returns a list
    var index = vm.FindIndex(x => x.ID == viewModel.ID);
    vm[index] = viewModel;

    //might have to rename items in the ModelState.Errors dictionary
    //so they are associated with the correct item index.
    //first get the list of errors. As viewModel is not a list for this method
    //they will have keys like "PropertyName".
    //For a listItem need renaming to something like "[#].PropertyName" (# = index)
    var errs = from ms in ModelState
             where ms.Value.Errors.Any()
             let fieldKey = ms.Key
             let errors = ms.Value.Errors
             from error in errors
             select new {fieldKey, error.ErrorMessage};

    //clear the ModelState, and then re-add any model-errors with the renamed key
    ModelState.Clear();
    foreach(var item in errs) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(
             String.Format("[{0}].{1}", index, item.fieldKey), item.ErrorMessage);
    }

    return View("ItemsViewModels", vm);
}
```

In addition you might need to rename your form elements so that the model binder treats them as list items after postback. I'm not 100% sure this is necessary though.

**If you can use ajax this becomes neater...**

It looks like your index Model is a `List<ItemViewModel>`

Then your Main view (Index.cshtml) would be something like..

```
@model List<ItemViewModel>
... 
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div id="@String.Format("partialContainer{0}", Model[i].ID)">
    @Html.Partial("Partial1", Model[i])
    </div>
}
```

(notice that the ID of the container div is something that we can reference as the ajax update target)
And then have your partial Views use the relevant partial Models

Eg Partial1.cshtml:

```
@model ItemViewModel
... etc
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RefreshPartial", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions() { 
UpdateTargetId = String.Format("partialContainer{0}", Model.ID), HttpMethod = "Post" }, null)) 
{  
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1); 
    @* form controls... *@
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

Comment: I updated my question at bottom. I am not allowed to use ajax. I HAVE to refresh the whole list WITH the validation_failed_partial.

Comment: In my opinion what the customer wants is not possible without ajax.

Comment: Anything is possible... just might not be practical. I've updated the answer with an idea for how to achieve what is being asked for (but not a full implementation yet) I think that the key to your issue is renaming the errors in the ModelState.Errors dictionary from `[0].Prop` (or just `Prop` in your case) to `[#].Prop` - where # is the index of your posted back item

Comment: My team mate said I have no idea how mvc works just because I can not make this default task work pfffhhh... Since when do I return an invalid list in mvc? I told him of your hack ideas but he said thats crap not kidding.

Comment: @Pascal heh :) Well this IS a hack. The posted back model is supposed to be the whole thing in MVC (or at least enough of it for the model binder to reconstruct the model) If it were done with AJAX that would be clean. Anyway - I've fleshed out the hack with a bit more detail in the answer